# Certbot - Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle [Archlinux]

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, archlinux, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'am trying to generate certificate from Let's Encrypt It over certbot (package ver. 0.21.1.-1), but i'am getting error. I'am using webroot module.

```
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I don't have there file with this filename. Should i generate it, download?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: At this point in time the answer is to install or reinstall the ca-certificates-utils package as this provides the file :

`pacman -Qo /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt is owned by ca-certificates-utils 20220905-1

Answer (score 11):

Maybe /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt is not exist.

Try running `sudo update-ca-certificates` to create it.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing `cd /etc/ssl/certs` followed by `cat *.pem >> ca-certificates.crt`

Not the most elegant solution and you'll have to delete the file and redo it every time the ca-certificates package (or its dependents) update...

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo pacman -S ca-certificates` to install the core certificates

Comment: Package ca-certificates is in certbot dependencies. I tried to reinstall it, but it don't helped.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `update-ca-trust` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the original `ca-certificates.crt` file is missing.

In my case, I removed it when adding a new certificate file containing my website.com as a CN (Common Name). Fortunately, I had a backup copy of that file.

If you have that file, just put it again in the directory:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Or try to add a new one with the same name.